# How do I view the Meteor app running on the VM at localhost:3000?

Tags: meteor

Hi I'm trying to make my first meteor app. I just made an app and have run it. I've also upgraded to latest meteorite and meteor. I just created a new app and have run it.

```
App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

But I cannot view this webpage on my host computer. I'm running meteor on an ubuntu vm.

It was working before I updated meteorite and meteor and installed the iron-router package to an app I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too was unable to connect to the Meteor App that was being developed on a centos VM.
The followuing worked:
Setup:
Windows 7/8.1 with Following tools installed:
Putty
VMW Workstation
Centos VM (Server or GUI based)
Chrome/Mozilla Browsers

1. Launch the VM from VMW Workstation
2. Console into the VM using Putty
3. Launch the Meteor App. Will show its listening at localhost?3000
4. Launch a new session of Putty.
5. Go To SSH-Tunnels - Source: 3000, Destination - Localhost:3000. Save this settings
6. Connect to the VM with these settings
7. Launch the browser and and navigate to localhost:3000

Worked for me, hope does for all

Answer (score 1):

check in the console you might have the error as template is not defined, Meteor is not defined etc...

Comment: No errors at all in the console. I can do 'curl http://localhost:3000' with SSH to the box and I can see the source code of the app. But I can't access it on my host computer.

Answer (score 0):

As you have determined, the message on the vm regarding localhost:3000 refers to the vm that is running meteor, and localhost on your computer refers to your computer.

The secure fix for this is to create an encrypted tunnel to connect localhost:3000 on your computer to localhost:3000 on the remote computer.

1. Start the meteor app on the VM so that you get the message about it being ready on localhost:3000
2. On the local computer open another terminal window and initiate a second connection to the VM with:

`ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000 yourUSER@remoteHOST`

This assumes you are running Linux.  If you are on Windows, look at the options for your SSH client.  It may have similar options to create tunnels.

3. Open a web browser on your local computer and go to `http://localhost:3000`

The ssh tunnelling software will sense the connection to localhost:3000 on your computer and will connect you to localhost:3000 on the remote, forwarding the data through an encrypted tunnel.

If this seems like a lot of trouble, there are paid developer platforms like http://nitrous.io that can run meteor and have a web based IDE that can simplify this sort of thing for you so you do not need to run the tunnel.  Another way to simplify is to not use a remote VM, but install Meteor on the home computer and only copy the code to a VM when it is finished and ready for production.

If you don't want to run on localhost:3000 at all, but on the webserver on port 80, you might check to see if there is an environment variable that switches the code from development mode to production.